# "upload" is not a function

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have an annoying problem. I've googled a bit and can't really find any good answers, so I'm hoping to find some help here.

I'm getting this error, which seems to be fairly common:

```
TypeError: Error #1006: update är inte en funktion.  // = update is not a function (english)
at se.qmd.spaceInvaders::ShipHandler/onEnterFrame()
```

Update definently is a function, so I really can't understand what the problem is.

My setup. I'm using Flashdevelop. I have a **Main** class, which is set as the document class in my **fla** file. 
I have a package structure with my Main class in the **src** folder, and my subclasses in **se.qmd.spaceInvaders** and **se.qmd.starLight**. I also use TweenMax and keep it in the "normal" package structure from the src folder.

In the Main class I add to the stage an instance of the class **LeGun** - which is also an "exported" movieclip in the fla file, an instance of the class StarHandler and an instance of the class ShipHandler. I also have a keyboard listener which with the help of an enterframe function moves my instance of the LeGun class. 
Fine, no problems. The StarHandler works like it should, and the ShipHandler works as it should up until i call 1 or 2 methods in the **Ship** class - which is also an "exported" movieclip in the fla file. The Ship class is of course the class that contains the Ship that is handled by the ShipHandler.

I'm including my ShipHandler and Ship classes below, and hope it doesn't make the post excede some length.
ShipHandler.as :

```
package se.qmd.spaceInvaders {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import se.qmd.spaceInvaders.Ship;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;

public class ShipHandler extends MovieClip {

    private var _shipArray:Array = [];
    private const NUM_START_SHIPS:int = 25;
    private var s:Stage = null;

    private var _directionX:Number = 1;
    private var _directionY:Number = 1;
    private var _velocityX:Number;
    private var _velocityY:Number;

    private const YBORDER_TOP:int = 50;
    private const YBORDER_BOTTOM:int = 525;

    public function ShipHandler(o:Stage) {

        s = o; // tar emot stage från main
        createObjects();

        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
    }   

    private function createObjects():void {

        for (var i:int = 0; i < NUM_START_SHIPS; i++) {

            var aShip:Ship = new Ship();
            aShip.x = Math.random() * (s.stageWidth - aShip.width) + aShip.width / 2;
            aShip.y = Math.random() * (s.stageHeight - aShip.height -135) + aShip.height / 2 + 55;
            this.addChild(aShip);
            _shipArray.push(aShip);
            aShip.startMove(Math.random(), Math.random());
        }           
    }   

    private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {

        for (var i:int = 0; i < _shipArray.length; i++) {

            var aShip:Ship = _shipArray[i] as Ship;
            aShip.update();
        }   
    }
}
}
```

Ship.as :

```
package se.qmd.spaceInvaders {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Ship extends MovieClip {

    private var _directionX:Number = 1;
    private var _directionY:Number = 1;
    private var _velocityX:Number;
    private var _velocityY:Number;

    private const YBORDER_TOP:int = 50;
    private const YBORDER_BOTTOM:int = 525;

    public function Ship() {

        //s = o; // tar emot stage  
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
    }

    private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void {

        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

        this.width = 50;
        this.height = 18;           
    }

    public function update():void {

        // x led vänster kant
        if(this.x <= this.width / 2) {

            this.x = this.width / 2;
            _directionX *= -1;
        }

        // x led höger kant
        if(this.x >= 800 - this.width / 2) {

            this.x = 800 - this.width/2;
            _directionX *= -1;
        }

        // y led top kant
        if(this.y <= YBORDER_TOP + this.height/2) {

            this.y = YBORDER_TOP + this.height / 2;
            _directionY *= -1;
        }

        // y led botten kant
        if(this.y >= YBORDER_BOTTOM - this.height/2) {

            this.y = YBORDER_BOTTOM - this.height / 2;
            _directionY *= -1;
        }

        this.x += _velocityX * _directionX;
        this.y += _velocityY * _directionY;
    }

    public function startMove(directionX:Number, directionY:Number):void {

        trace(directionX, directionY);
        _velocityX = 10;
        _velocityY = 10;

        if (directionX < 0.5) {

            _directionX = -1;
        }

        if (directionY < 0.5) {

            _directionY = -1;
        }
    }

    public function changeDirection():void {

        _directionX *= -1;
        _directionY *= -1;
    }   
}
}
```

As soon as i call either the methods startMove or update from the ShipHandler, i get the error i wrote above.
Would appreciate any help as it seems to me I must be doing something fundamentally wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like `Ship` is just a MovieClip (which is a dynamic class and hence the compiler is not complaining when you're trying to access a method that does not exist at compile-time.) MovieClips don't have an `update()` method, so when you try to invoke it, it cannot be found on the `Ship` instance.

Is the MovieClip in your FLA file really exported as `se.qmd.spaceInvaders.Ship` (and not just `Ship`)? If it's just `Ship`, that would explain why your written class is not assigned as the class of your ship graphics, leaving it to be just a simple MovieClip which would explain this error.

Comment: So easy solution.
Well you learn from all misstakes  :)  
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your original code and it works fine for me. I did not need to change anything.

Are you compiling from the Flash IDE? In that case, try cleaning the cache with **Control > Delete ASO files** like this:

[image]

---

Try casting the ship instead like this:

```
private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {

    for (var i:int = 0; i < _shipArray.length; i++) {

            var aShip:Ship = Ship(_shipArray[i]);
            if(aShip)
                aShip.update();
            else
                throw Error("ship is null at position " + i)
    }   
}
```

Or use Vector instead of Array:

```
var _shipArray : Vector.<Ship> = new Vector.<Ship>();
```

Comment: Getting the same error if i try your first example :(

Don't know how to use Vectors yet, and I'm using an array in a very similar way in my StarHandler class, and it works there...

Comment: Do you get the same error when you use my code or do you get the custom error (ship is null at position x)?